# Java HashMap check if existing in file

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

How to compare the Keys of HashMap to String?

I have text file that has 100k number of lines and putting it into HashMap.

For Example my HashMap looks like this :

```
{test1=1}
{test2=2}
up to...
{test100000=100000}
```

And in other hand I'm reading a 1million number of lines of a text file.
The text file has data like this :

```
test1,first,input1
test2,second,input2
up to..
test1000000,1million,input1million
```

and I'm splitting it up the line with "," and i'm just getting the first data of the line. which is "test words" for example :

```
test1
test2
```

So what I want to do is, I want to check if the keys of my HashMap is existing in text file.

**My problem is, my other text file is bigger than to lines of my HashMap so it might be throw a NullPointerException or NoSuchElement.**

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File small = new File("C:\test\\testfolder\\small.txt"); // text file (100k+lines) put in hashmap
        File large = new File("C:\test\\testfolder\\big.txt"); // text file (1million+ lines) just read

        ArrayList<String> smallData= new ArrayList();
        smallData.addAll(getData(small));

        Map<String,String> smallMap = new HashMap();
        smallMap = MapSmallFile(smallData);

    try{
            LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(large,"UTF-8");
            String line;
        String[] large_data;

        while(it.hasNext()){
                line = it.nextLine();
                large_data = StringUtils.split(line, (","));



        //do the comparing here
             if(large_data[0].equalsIgnoreCase(?????)


            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static ArrayList<String> getData(File file) {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
        String line;
          try{
            LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file,"UTF-8");
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    line = it.nextLine();
                    data.add(line);     
             }
                it.close();
          }
                      catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      return data;
    }

private static Map<String,String> MapSmallFile(ArrayList<String> inputlist){
       String[] data;
       Map<String,String> hashmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
       for(int i=0; i<inputlist.size(); i++){
           data = inputlist.get(i).split(",");
           hashmap.put(data[0], data[1]);
       }
       return hashmap;
    }
```

Comment: Hash map get method does not throw exception when key is not there, it returns value as null.

Comment: But the thing is, how can I check if the keys is existing in the lines?

Comment: @tutuyokgaming You can use `HashMap.keySet()` which returns a `List<K>` and use `List.contains` to check.

Comment: @M.Shaw but with that logic i'm just checking if the List has data as the same as in the line. But what I want is to compare the List of<K> if it's existing in data of line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems better to use HashMap's boolean containsKey(Object key) method instead of the direct invocation of equalsIgnore..() in main(). 
If necessary, you may create your own class implement interface Map, and make it a delegator of its HashMap-typed field for customized management of key comparisons.(You may override equals() and hashCode() for keys. Item 8 and Item 9 in Effective Java 2nd ed. by Josh Bloch will give you detailed guide.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but the amount of code and dependencies could be considerably reduced if you are using Java 8.

Also, if you want to do case-insensitive comparison, it might be worth considering calling `toLowerCase()` on the keys before inserting/searching in the map.

Here is some possible Java 8 code that you could use:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // text file (100k+lines) put in hashmap
    Path small = Paths.get("C:\\test\\testfolder\\small.txt");
    // text file (1million+ lines) just read
    Path large = Paths.get("C:\\test\\testfolder\\big.txt");

    try
    {
      Map<String, String> smallMap = Files.lines(small, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
          .map(s -> s.split(","))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(ss -> ss[0].toLowerCase(), ss -> ss[1]));

      Files.lines(large, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
          .map(s -> s.split(",")[0].toLowerCase())
          .filter(s -> smallMap.containsKey(s))
          .forEachOrdered(s -> processData(s, smallMap.get(s)));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void processData(String key, String value)
  {
    // Do what needs to be done with the matching key/value
  }
```